# Stuck with 15 mins login-in message "Please wait for the User Profile Service" or "Welcome" on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

Every time I login, Windows gets stuck with the message "Please wait for the User Profile Service" for about 15 minutes:
[image: Login pic]

This is a windows 10 professional 21H1 with all the latest updated applied nightly. I run it within a Virtual machine. It belongs to a company's domain.

I have tried more then a few things along the last months to get more information and/or improve this login performance. The most I could do was to make this "profile service" message appear, instead of the "Welcome" message.

[This blog](https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-server-hangs-at-please-wait-for-the-user-profile-service) gave me the best advice as to fell like I was getting somewhere, but the issue remained.

Microsoft [seems to acknowledge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/d2b47c4e-8819-a38c-7b37-ff0a79927035) it as a bug, but applying the suggested patch does not resolve it for me.

How to get more log details about this, or even better, resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the files & folders in 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp' worked for me. Give it a try; you don't need those files anyway.
For more info: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/users-file-is-taking-up-all-the-space-on-my-c/92161513-6182-46ad-877a-912e90cc0b40

Answer (score 1):

1 Logon as administrative user, then
2 download and run procmon, then
3 disconnect the session and switch to your problem user (procmon keeps running, since you only switch users, you don't logoff that admin) ->take note of the exact time you started to logon and again the exact time when it succeeded
4 switch users again and look what happened between these two points in time

### Attention: people with no procmon experience will be overwhelmed by the log size. You need to use filtering and this investigation will take time.

You should also boot the machine to safe mode with networking and see if logon is fast, there.

Ultimately, if that is only for one machine, you could go to these three steps:
1 re-create that user profile
2 if no better, inplace-upgrade the machine
3 if no better, re-install

Answer (score 0):

Today a miracle happened, talking with the infra-structure department we decided to upgrade **windows 10 to 21H2**. It was a painful 5h upgrade process with 2h down time rebooting. But it was 10 months stuck with 15 minutes to login...

**Once the upgrade was done, the login problem was gone!!!**

We are not sure if it the upgrade fixed bugs or if the upgrade process cleaned-up something, but the problem is gone!

Comment: From 21H1 to 21H2 it takes an enablement package, less than 100 kilobytes in size. You performed the full upgrade, which was unneeded (normally), but helped. So let's see what the inplace upgrade does: It repairs system file corruption and it resets many system security settings. One of the two will have helped.